# How to split the first, middle and last name from a fullname field into FirstName(first and middle name) and LastName(last name)

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
First Name              Last Name
Saafiayh Sal Radiqah    Adams
Abdurahmaan             Kareem
Jean-Paul               De-Beer
```

'FirstName' = substring(d.FullName, 1, (charindex(' ', d.FullName + ' ')-1)),
'Surname' = substring(d.FullName, len(d.FullName)-charindex(' ',reverse(d.FullName))+1,len(d.FullName))

Comment: I can't interpret the question.  The title implies a full name field turning into three columns.  The data then shows two columns of data.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff, i want to combine (FirstName and Middle Name) into FirstName field

Comment: What if your last name has 2 spaces?

Comment: @Rajat then it needs to display both if there isnt any spaces then display one last name

Comment: @saafiyah If both first name and last name can have variable number of delimiters, I am not sure it's possible to accomplish this. You need to define some rule that dictates the separability between first and last name.

Comment: @Rajat and if there is no spaces in last name? i have a query but its not returning the middle name. i need assistance.

Comment: @saafiyah See my answer

Comment: thank you @Rajat, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have a space in the last name, you could do something like this.

```
with cte (txt) as 

(select 'Ben Burr' union all 
select 'Ben J Burr')

select replace(txt,right(txt,charindex(' ',reverse(txt))),'') as first_name --replaces last name with nothing,
       right(txt,charindex(' ',reverse(txt))-1) as last_name --gets the name after the last occurrence of a space
from cte;
```

A slightly less verbose method using `cross apply`

```
with cte (txt) as 

(select 'Ben Burr' union all 
select 'Ben J Burr')

select replace(txt,' ' + last_name,'') first_name, 
       last_name
from cte t1
cross apply (select right(txt,charindex(' ',reverse(txt))-1) last_name) t2;
```